# Write to input stream of opened terminal

Tags: java

I am having trouble writing to a command prompt that I can open via `ProcessBuilder`.

I have the following:

```
public class Terminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> launch = new ArrayList<String>();
        launch.add("cmd");
        launch.add("/c");
        launch.add("start");
        launch.add("cmd.exe");
        launch.add("/k");

        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(launch);
            Process process = builder.start();
            OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
            InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

            w.write("dir");
            w.flush();
            w.close();

        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And this successfully opens a new Windows command prompt. But it never writes `dir` to it. The prompt just opens and only displays the directory from which `java Terminal` was issued.

***How can I actively write to a terminal opened via a Process?***

**Edit:**
If I change the command string list to `"cmd.exe /k start dir"` then the newly spawned command prompt does in  fact issue the "dir" command and display it in the new terminal. **I cannot seem to find the correct manner to access the stream for writing new commands to it.**

```
public class Terminal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> launch = new ArrayList<String>();
        launch.add("cmd");
        launch.add("/k");
        launch.add("start");
        launch.add("dir");

        try {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(launch).start();
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a look at what `cmd /c start cmd /k` does:

- `cmd /c` starts a command prompt, executes the following commands, **then exits**.
- `start` spawns a new process with the given commands
- `cmd /k` expects a command (which you dont provide), executes it, then *remains open*

So: You start two instances of `cmd`. The second instance is started using `start`, which spawns a new process. You expect `"dir"` to show up in the second process, while it is being written to the first. Unfortunately, the first terminates immediately after calling `start` since you started it with `/c`.

Try changing `/c` to `/k`, then the `"dir"` should show up in the first window.

Comment: If the only command is `cmd`, no other terminal opens. If I change to `cmd /k start` it opens, but `dir` doesnt execute. If I change to `start cmd /k`, says it cant find `"start"`. That latter will work if you execute it directly in an opened command prompt. I am already running `java Terminal` from a command prompt; I need it to open another command prompt for reading/writing to.

Comment: What appears to be happening is that when `"cmd /c"` or `"cmd /k"` are issued, the current command prompt header changes rather than creating a new command prompt. The only time a new one appears is when calling the `"start cmd"` string.

Comment: Please see my edit; seems that I just cannot access the new process streams for I/O correctly.